# Ruby's Faraday - include the same param multiple times

Tags: ruby, api, url-parameters, faraday

I'm working against an API that forces me to send the same parameter's name multiple times to cascade different filtering criteria. So a sample api GET call looks like this:

```
GET http://api.site.com/search?a=b1&a=b2&a=b3&a=c2
```

I'm using Faraday for my REST adapter, which takes its URL parameters as a Hash (therefore - it has unique keys). This means I cannot do something like this:

```
response = Faraday.new({
  url: 'http://api.site.com/search'
  params: { a: 'b1', a: 'b2', a: 'b3', a: 'c2' } # => nay
}).get
```

I tried to hack on the url right before the request is sent:

```
connection = Faraday.new(url: 'http://api.site.com/search')
url        = connection.url_prefix.to_s
full_url   = "#{ url }?a=b1&a=b2&a=b3&a=c2"
response   = connection.get( full_url )
```

Which did not work - when I debug the response I see that the actual url sent to the API server is:

```
GET http://api.site.com/search?a[]=b1&a[]=b2&a[]=b3&a[]=c2
```

I have no way to change the API. Is there a way to keep working with Faraday and solve this in an elegant way? thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a while now. I ended up digging through the Faraday code, and found exactly this use case in the test suite.

```
:params => {:color => ['red', 'blue']}
```

should yield

```
color=red&color=blue
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this exact behavior only exists in v0.9+ and isn't the default (previous versions and the default in 0.9 encode it as `color%5B%5D=red&color%5B%5D=blue`). To get `color=red&color=blue` you need to set the `param_encoder` option to `Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want upgrade to 0.9.x

```
module Faraday
  module Utils
    def build_nested_query(value, prefix = nil)
      case value
      when Array
        value.map { |v| build_nested_query(v, "#{prefix}") }.join("&")
      when Hash
        value.map { |k, v|
          build_nested_query(v, prefix ? "#{prefix}%5B#{escape(k)}%5D" : escape(k))
        }.join("&")
      when NilClass
        prefix
      else
        raise ArgumentError, "value must be a Hash" if prefix.nil?
        "#{prefix}=#{escape(value)}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you call Faraday is not correct. You need to define a connection first (without parameters), and then you call the HTTP method on that connection.

Something like this:

```
require 'faraday'

client = Faraday::Connection.new :url => "http://api.twitter.com" do |builder|
    builder.response :logger
    # some middleware that helps to process a request/response comes here
end

client.get "search", { a: 1, b:2 }
```

This should build you this request:

```
I, [2013-02-05T15:15:40.665955 #57012]  INFO -- : get http://api.twitter.com/search?a=1&b=2
```