# passing array of url params in faraday

Tags: ruby, arrays, faraday

I'm new to Faraday and trying to learn how to pass an array for url params. My code looks like this:

```
require 'faraday'

conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://foo.com:8888') do |faraday|
  faraday.request :url_encoded
  faraday.response :logger
  faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end

response = conn.get '/api/endpoint', { :bar => ['baz', 'qux'] }
response.body
```

When I debug, I see that the URL is getting encoded as:

```
INFO -- : get http://foo.com:8888/api/endpoint?bar[]=baz&bar[]=qux
```

instead of `http://foo.com:8888/api/endpoint?bar=baz&bar=qux`. How do I get faraday to encode the URL without the `[]` when I'm passing an array of params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see why this is happening now.

This issue is actually fixed on Faraday ver 0.9+, but that's only avaliable as an RC.

So two choices:
Change your code to look like this (monkey patch, taken from [Ruby's Faraday - include the same param multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551057/rubys-faraday-include-the-same-param-multiple-times))

```
require 'faraday'

module Faraday
  module Utils
    def build_nested_query(value, prefix = nil)
      case value
      when Array
        value.map { |v| build_nested_query(v, "#{prefix}") }.join("&")
      when Hash
        value.map { |k, v|
          build_nested_query(v, prefix ? "#{prefix}%5B#{escape(k)}%5D" : escape(k))
        }.join("&")
      when NilClass
        prefix
      else
        raise ArgumentError, "value must be a Hash" if prefix.nil?
        "#{prefix}=#{escape(value)}"
      end
    end
  end
end

conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://foo.com:8888') do |faraday|
  faraday.request :url_encoded
  faraday.response :logger
  faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end

response = conn.get '/api/endpoint', { :bar => ['baz', 'qux'] }
response.body
```

Or use the pre-release 0.9 version of faraday

```
gem install faraday --pre
```

and add this to your code:

```
faraday.params_encoder = Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder
```

Which will stop it from adding the `[]` symbols.

Comment: Sorry to accept and then unaccept. I thought this was working, but when I added `faraday.params_encoder Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder` to the `do` block I got `undefined method params_encoder' for #<Faraday::Connection:0x007fd52c05fd58> (NoMethodError)`. Any ideas?

Comment: params_encoder is only in the latest version of faraday. Make sure you've defined the version in your Gemfile like so:`gem "faraday", "~> 0.9.0.rc5"`. That should fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment so I'll say this: The above answer worked for me, and I have upvoted it, but here's my specific example (I had to move the call to FlatParamsEncoder, I had it in the wrong method initially:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'faraday', '~> 0.9.0.rc5'

#lib/api_wrapper/faraday_adapter.rb
def patch
  connection.patch do |req|
    req.options.params_encoder = Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    req.url "/api/v1/#{end_point}", @request.params
  end
end

def connection
  faraday_client = Faraday.new(:url => base_url) do |faraday|
    faraday.response :logger if Rails.env.development?
    faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter # make requests with Net::HTTP
  end
  faraday_client.basic_auth(username, password)
  faraday_client
end
```